# Formatting cells is not copied to the next line in the Excel table

Tags: excel

I have a strange problem with Excel

On each table, when I open a new row, the formatting patterns are automatically copied to the next row

This table does not occur

I have two designs, bold, and currency format

That's what happens when I make a new line

Bold design of the **first line** is canceled

I checked if there is a macro / conditional formatting on it, I did not find anything

Can anyone advise me what the problem is?

example:
The first line is correct except that it is not bold,
The last line is the right design

[image]

Comment: Try this - select any cell in this column, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. This will select the entire column of your table. Apply Bold format to this selection. And then try to add another row. Hopefully the next row will have Bold format automatically applied.

Comment: The extra line is indeed highlighted, only the first line is not bold,
Even if I made it bold,

Answer (score 0):

I skipped the problem, that I did conditional formatting, with the formula

`=SUM(1+1)=2`

And it's always true

And so it always stays in bold